# Calculating dynamic Month over Month

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate Month over Month % Revenue change on data rows using R. For example my current data is:

```
Booking.Date   Revenue  Month
  4/1/2018      3160    April
  4/1/2018     12656    April 
  4/1/2018      5157    April
  5/8/2018     12152      May
  5/8/2018      2824      May
  5/8/2018      4600      May
  6/30/2018     6936     June
  6/30/2018    17298     June
  6/30/2018    9625      June
```

I want to make a dynamic function in R which calculates the Revenue

```
MoM((Revenue_month2-Revenue_month1)/Revenue_month1)*100)
```

for any new month.

The output should be similar to:

```
 Month     Revenue_MoM 
 April         3% 
   May        -8% 
  June         50%
```

and so on.

Comment: How did you calculate the 3%, -8% and 50%?

Comment: The numbers are just for reference. The output format should be similar

Comment: My answer is not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

I got a `data.table` solution, only the ordering needs to be fixed, by making the month a proper date function. But it should give you an idea. Please keep in mind that for the first month there's no way to calculate a growth rate. I used the logarithmic growth rate, which is in my opinion the best way, but you can easily switch that to any other growth rate calculation.

```
  library(data.table)
  dt <- structure(list(Booking.Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("4/1/2018", "5/8/2018", "6/30/2018"
                                            ), class = "factor")
                 , Revenue = c(3160L, 12656L, 5157L, 12152L,  2824L, 4600L, 6936L, 17298L, 9625L)
                 , Month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("April", "June", "May"), class = "factor"))
                , row.names = c(NA, -9L)
            , class = c("data.table","data.frame"))
  # Change the month column into date one
  # Setting the locale, so that the months can be converted
  Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")
  dt[, `:=`(Month.Date = as.Date(paste0("2018-",Month,"-01"), tryFormats = "%Y-%B-%d"))
  dt[,.(Sum.Revenue = sum(Revenue)), by = list(Month.Date)][, .(Month.Date
                                                     , Sum.Revenue
                                                     , Change.Revenue = log(Sum.Revenue) - log(shift(Sum.Revenue, n =1L, type = "lag"))
                                                                                               )]
 # Calculations, based on the normal growth rate calculation
 dt[,.(Sum.Revenue = sum(Revenue)), by = list(Month.Date)][, .(Month.Date
                                                     , Sum.Revenue
                                                     , Change.Revenue = (Sum.Revenue - shift(Sum.Revenue, n =1L, type = "lag"))/shift(Sum.Revenue, n =1L, type = "lag")
                                                                                               )]
```